# How to use href in shiny notificationItem?

Tags: shiny

```
dropdownMenu(type = "notifications",
             notificationItem(
               text = "profile updated",
               icon("users"),href="#shiny-tab-attendance" 
             ),
             notificationItem(
               text = "new transport route",
               icon("truck"),
               status = "success"
             ),
             notificationItem(
               text = "Server maintainace",
               icon = icon("exclamation-triangle"),
               status = "warning"
             )
),
```

where shiny-tab-attendance is id of attendance tab? On clicking the item its not navigating to this tab. Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

Find one way

creating notification item on server:

```
ddd=notificationItem(icon = icon("exclamation-triangle"), status = "danger",paste0("noti"))
```

then change tags

```
ddd$children[[1]]=a(href="#shiny-tab-attendance","data-toggle"="tab", "data-value"="attendance",list(ddd$children[[1]]$children))
```

## Update

as @Fabian Gehring told there is problem with such method ( not work after navigation)

for other variant [see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35796170/5018792)

Comment: Solution seems to work right after startup, but not after some clicking on the MenuItem. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35728623/linking-notification-to-tab-in-shinydashboard