# Linking notification to tab in shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'd like to link a notificattion to an (internal) tab.

To do so I came accross this: [How to use href in shiny notificationItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30637847/how-to-use-href-in-shiny-notificationitem)

This seems to work right after loading of the app, but after some navigation in the sidebar the link does not work anymore.

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

notification <- notificationItem(icon = icon("exclamation-triangle"), status = "danger", paste0("noti"))
notification$children[[1]] <- a(href="#shiny-tab-dashboard","data-toggle"="tab", "data-value"="dashboard",list(notification$children[[1]]$children))

header <- dashboardHeader(dropdownMenu(notification), title = "Dashboard")

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
    menuItem("Test",
             menuSubItem("test1", tabName = "test1", href = NULL, newtab = TRUE,
                         icon = shiny::icon("angle-double-right"), selected = F),
             menuSubItem("test2", tabName = "test2", href = NULL, newtab = TRUE,
                         icon = shiny::icon("angle-double-right"), selected = T)
    )
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
            h2("Dashboard tab content")
    ),

    tabItem(tabName = "test1",
            h2("Widgets tab1 content")
    ),

    tabItem(tabName = "test2",
            h2("Widgets tab2 content")
    )
  )
)

dashboardPage(
  header,
  sidebar,
  body
)
```

server.R

```
function(input, output) {

}
```

Comment: Hmmm.. Investigated a bit more on this. When inspecting the html, both hrefs seem to be identical:
<a href= "#shiny-tab-dashboard" data-toggle= "tab" dat-value=dashboard" aria-expanded= "true>, the only difference is the following i-Class:
For the notification it's <i class = "fa fa-exclamation-triangle text-danger"></i>
For the menuItem it's <i class= "fa fa-dashboard"></i><span>Dashboard</span>
Don't expect this to be the reason (since it's working right after startup). Ideas still highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As before bad hack variant )

## ideas

1) Add onclick

2) from js to shiny

```
 tags$script(HTML("function clickFunction(link){ 
                       Shiny.onInputChange('linkClicked',link);
    }"))
```

3) `observeEvent` + re-render menu

4) If dont wnat to re-render full menu your can use menu as

```
output$dropdown=renderMenu({dropdownMenu(type = "tasks", badgeStatus = "danger",.list = d$tasks_now)})
```

where `d=reactiveValues({tasks_now=get_noti()})`
and in observeEvent update `d$tasks_now`

## Server

```
library(shiny)

get_noti=function(){
  notification <- notificationItem(icon = icon("exclamation-triangle"), status = "danger", paste0("noti"))
  notification$children[[1]] <- a(href="#shiny-tab-dashboard","onclick"=paste0("clickFunction('",paste0(substr(as.character(runif(1, 0, 1)),1,6),"noti"),"'); return false;"),list(notification$children[[1]]$children))
  return(notification)
}

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$dropdown=renderMenu({dropdownMenu(get_noti())})
  observeEvent(input$linkClicked,{
    print(input$linkClicked)
    updateTabItems(session,"sidemenu",selected = "dashboard")
    output$dropdown=renderMenu({dropdownMenu(get_noti())})
  })
  })
```

## UI

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
header <- dashboardHeader(dropdownMenuOutput('dropdown'), title = "Dashboard")
 sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(id="sidemenu",
    menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
    menuItem("Test",
             menuSubItem("test1", tabName = "test1", href = NULL, newtab = TRUE,
                         icon = shiny::icon("angle-double-right"), selected = F),
             menuSubItem("test2", tabName = "test2", href = NULL, newtab = TRUE,
                         icon = shiny::icon("angle-double-right"), selected = T)
    )))
body <- dashboardBody(
  tags$script(HTML("function clickFunction(link){ 
                       Shiny.onInputChange('linkClicked',link);
    }")),
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
            h2("Dashboard tab content")
    ),

    tabItem(tabName = "test1",
            h2("Widgets tab1 content")
    ),

    tabItem(tabName = "test2",
            h2("Widgets tab2 content")
    )
  )
)
dashboardPage(
  header,
  sidebar,
  body
)
```

Comment: It's working, great thank, just had to add 

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
header <- dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard", dropdownMenuOutput("dropdown"))

add the top of UI.

Just for a better understanding: Do you know, why the former solution (without onClick) breaks after same chlicking on the menues?

Comment: @FabianGehring not fully understand what had to add? suggest edit and i see it .. thx

Comment: @FabianGehring no i dont know why previous not worked, but i knew that there are problem with it)